# Gather current variables from multiple select forms

Tags: jquery, html, select, jquery-selectors

I am trying to gather all the current choices from 4 different select forms in one function. Then I am going to output a price according to the choices.

I can already output the separate choices for somewhat of UI, but I can't figure it out how to get all the variables in one function.

```
        <div class="col-md-6 center">
            <h4>Title</h4>
            <img name="division" src="/img/div/bronze_1.png" alt="Bronze">
            <select class="form-control" id="current">
                <option value="0" selected>Bronze</option>
                <option value="1">Silver</option>
                <option value="2">Gold</option>
                <option value="3">Platinum</option>
                <option value="4">Diamond</option>
            </select>
            <select class="form-control m10" id="currentdiv">
                <option value="1">Division I</option>
                <option value="2">Division II</option>
                <option value="3">Division III</option>
                <option value="4">Division IV</option>
                <option value="5" selected>Division V</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-md-center text-sm-center">
            <h4>Desired Rank</h4>
            <img name="desired-division" src="/img/div/bronze_1.png" alt="Bronze">
            <select class="form-control" id="desired">
                <option value="0" selected>Bronze</option>
                <option value="1">Silver</option>
                <option value="2">Gold</option>
                <option value="3">Platinum</option>
                <option value="4">Diamond</option>
            </select>
            <select class="form-control m10" id="desireddiv">
                <option value="1">Division I</option>
                <option value="2">Division II</option>
                <option value="3">Division III</option>
                <option value="4" selected>Division IV</option>
                <option value="5">Division V</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 text-md-center text-sm-center" id="order">
    <h4>Your Order</h4>
    <div class="alert-info">
        <p class="lead">From <span id="currentspan">Bronze</span> <span id="currentdivspan">V</span> to <span id="desiredspan">Bronze</span> <span id="desireddivspan">IV</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="alert-success">
    <p>Price: <span id="price">8</span>€  ($<span class="priceusd">8.92</span>)</p>
    </div><img src="/img/payment-badges.png" alt="payment badges">
    <a href="/order.php" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary m25"><i class="fa fa-paypal" aria-hidden="true"></i> Order Now</a>
</div>
```

```js
$("#current").change(function(){
    var val4 = parseInt($('#current').val());
    var pictureList = [
        "/img/div/bronze_1.png",
        "/img/div/silver_1.png",
        "/img/div/gold_1.png",
        "/img/div/platinum_1.png",
        "/img/div/diamond_1.png" ];
        $("img[name=division]").attr("src",pictureList[val4]);
    var text;
    switch (val4) {
        case 0:
            text = "Bronze";
            break;
        case 1:
            text = "Silver";
            break;
        case 2:
            text = "Gold";
            break;
        case 3:
            text = "Platinum";
            break;
        case 4:
            text = "Diamond";
            break;
    }
    $("#currentspan").html(text);
});

$("#currentdiv").change(function(){
    var cdiv = parseInt($('#currentdiv').val());
    var cdivtext;
    switch (cdiv) {
        case 1:
            cdivtext = "I";
            break;
        case 2:
            cdivtext = "II";
            break;
        case 3:
            cdivtext = "III";
            break;
        case 4:
            cdivtext = "IV";
            break;
        case 5:
            cdivtext = "V";
            break;
    }
    $("#currentdivspan").html(cdivtext)
});
```

Comment: where is your javascript and your form tag?

Comment: what is the formula for you price?

Comment: I believe form tag is unnecessary right now, because I'm modifying all the information real time. Same goes for the formula, it will be simple math, the problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to output all the varaibles from selections in one function to do the price math :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the selected option you do the following:

```
var selected_options = [];
$('select.form-control').change(function(){
    selected_options = $('select.form-control').find('option:selected').map(function(){return $(this).val();});
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I can see an array now, is it possible to make it refresh every time there's a change in the form?

Comment: Thank you! It works. I will try to do the price math from here.